# About Oracle partitioning and access multiples partition segments

Tags: oracle

I have read that sometimes having a bad partitioning is worse to performance instead of having no partition if the query don't use the `partition keys` to access the data in the specific partition, and so Oracle need to access several partition segments.

But why exactly is worse to access for example, five partition segments of 10gb instead of a big segments of 50gb (no partitioning)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the query plan.

In the worst case, you have an index that is equipartitioned with the table (as indexes on partitioned tables normally are) that can be used to identify the handful of rows you are interested in.  If you write a query that uses that index on a non-partitioned table, you only have to do 1 seek on the index (O(log(n) if you're into Big O notation).  If you run that same query on a partitioned table without the partition key, you'd have to do 1 seek on the index per partition (O(M log(n))).  As the number of partitions increases, these queries do worse and worse.

You could build the index as non-partitioned to prevent this sort of query from getting slower when you partition the table.  But that often makes it harder to benefit from other benefits of partitioning such as being able to quickly drop a partition without needing to do significant amounts of index maintenance.

If your queries are doing table scans, it is unlikely that scanning 5 10 GB partitions would be slower than scanning 1 50 GB table.  If anything, having 5 partitions may make it easier for the database to run the scans in parallel.

The important takeaway is that partitioning isn't a fast=true option.  It's something that may have serious performance benefits given the right workloads.  But it's not something you can naively apply everywhere without analysis.